# jquery sortable with laravel doesn't work

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a question about a sortable menu in laravel. If i load my page it gives me a fatal error that says "Class 'Input' not found in web.php line 49".

this is whats on line 49: "$itemID = Input::get('itemID');". Below you see the whole code block

```
Route::get('/custom',function(){
    $menu = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('order','ASC')->get();
    $itemID = Input::get('itemID');
    $itemIndex = Input::get('itemIndex');

    foreach($menu as $value){
        return DB::table('orders')->where('menu_id','=',$itemID)->update(array('order'=> $itemIndex));
    }});
```

This is my jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(function(){
      $("#menu").sortable({
        stop: function(){
          $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el) {
            var itemID = el.id;
            var itemIndex = $(el).index();
            $.ajax({
              url:'{{URL::to("custom")}}',
              type:'GET',
              dataType:'json',
              data: {itemID:itemID, itemIndex: itemIndex},
            })
          });
        }
      });
    });

    console.log(itemID);

});
```

This is my routes file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/custom', function(){
    return view('custom');
});

Route::get('/custom-menu', function(){
    return view('custom');
});


// function to view menu which are in order
Route::get('/', function () {
    $menu = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('order','ASC')->get();
    return view('custom-menu',['menus'=>$menu]);
});


// To view Menu That are in database
Route::get('custom',function(){
    $menu = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('order','ASC')->get();
    return view('custom',['menus'=>$menu]);
});

// Function to order menus
Route::get('/custom',function(){
        $menu = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('order','ASC')->get();
        $itemID = Input::get('itemID');
        $itemIndex = Input::get('itemIndex');

        foreach($menu as $value){
            return DB::table('orders')->where('menu_id','=',$itemID)->update(array('order'=> $itemIndex));
        }
});
```

Does someone know how i can fix this error?

Comment: try Use Input; in web.php

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

or add

'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,

in config/app.php aliases
and 
place `use Input`;in web.php

Comment: If i do that it says "The use statement with non-compound name 'Input' has no effect"

Comment: If i put "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;" in my web.php file it loads a zero on my page

Comment: try with Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('itemIndex');

Comment: If i do that i get:  parse error, expecting `','' or `';''

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the request from your routes file, [use `$request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/custom',function(Request $request) {
    $itemID = $request->itemID;
    // ...
```

**UPDATE**

There is another problem in this code:

```
foreach($menu as $value){
    return DB::table('orders')->where('menu_id','=',$itemID)->update(array('order'=> $itemIndex));
}});
```

This will start to iterate over each `$menu` you find in the first query (`$menu = DB::table ...`), but it `return`s after the first one.  That means it will never update all your items, only the first one.

In your comment you said `it returns 0`.  From [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries):

> The update method should be used to update existing records in the database. The number of rows affected by the statement will be returned

So, if you are looking at the response sent to your AJAX call, and you are seeing `0`, it means that for the first `$menu` to be updated, no records were actually updated.

To update all records, try just removing the return from the loop, so it completes:

```
foreach($menu as $value){
    DB::table('orders')->where('menu_id','=',$itemID)->update(array('order'=> $itemIndex));
}});

return;
```

Comment: It keeps returning a zero

Comment: @CorneliusVanErkelens What returns 0? I tested the code in my answer and it works.

Comment: @CorneliusVanErkelens I found what you probably mean, and updated my answer.